# how does HTTP "session" reconstruction work?

Tags: http, network-programming, sniffing

I have found this tool online: http://www.unleashnetworks.com/products/unsniff.html

How does this work? Are they assuming that all HTTP traffic for a session occurs in the same TCP session, and then just clumping all that data together? Is that a safe assumption?

I was under the impression that when I load a page, multiple TCP sessions could be running for that single page load (images, videos, flash, whatever).

This seems to get complicated when I think about having two browser tabs open that are loading pages at the same time..how could I differentiate one http "session" from another? Especially true if they are hitting the same page, right?

For that matter, how does the browser know which data incoming belongs to which tab? Does it keep track of TCP sessions belonging to an individual tab?

Edit:

When HTTP session is mentioned above, I am referring to all of the related HTTP transactions that it takes to, say, load a page.

By TCP session, I am literally referring to the handshake's SYN -> FIN packet lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

Although it might not be visible, the HTTP Session tracker is being passed to the server from the client as a parameter or as e cookie (header)

You might need to read about [HTTP session token](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29)

A session token is a unique identifier that is generated and sent from a server to a client to identify the current interaction session. The client usually stores and sends the token as an HTTP cookie and/or sends it as a parameter in GET or POST queries. The reason to use session tokens is that the client only has to handle the identifier—all session data is stored on the server (usually in a database, to which the client does not have direct access) linked to that identifier. Examples of the names that some programming languages use when naming their HTTP cookie include JSESSIONID (JSP), PHPSESSID (PHP), and ASPSESSIONID (ASP).

Comment: Are you saying that a cookie or session ID is always in use in the HTTP headers, regardless of whether one is stored by my browser or not?

Comment: Yes, a cookie or a parameter is always past in http communication

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the "Unsniff" app you link to, but I have used a few packet sniffers before (my favorite is [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)).  Usually you can differentiate sessions based on what host they are connected to.  So, for instance, if you have 2 tabs open and one is opened to www.google.com and the other is www.facebook.com, the packet sniffer should be able to tell you which session is pointed at which host (or at least give you an IP address, which you can then use to find the host.  see: [reverse lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup)).

Most times, multiple HTTP sessions will be open to one host.  This is the case when you're loading a site's various resources (CSS files, images, javascript, etc.).  Each of these resources will show up as a separate HTTP session (unless, of course, the connection is [persistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)... but your sniffer should be able to separate them anyway).  In this case, you (or the sniffer) will need to determine what was downloaded by looking at the actual data within the HTTP packet.

Comment: In your terms, HTTP session I am referring too would be loading a site's resources, as you mentioned. That is, lets say I am loading the same exact site on two tabs in the browser, at exactly the same time. How does the browser know to send the right HTTP responses to each tab? It seems to me in wireshark the only way I can tell is if keep-alive is on, and I am able to differentiate the two TCP connections. But I can't tell any difference between the two HTTP sessions

Comment: @Derek The tabs have separate TCP connections within the same HTTP session.

Comment: So was that kind of browsing not possible in previous versions of HTTP? Should I even account for those if I am trying to keep track of HTTP sessions, or just stick with 1.1

Comment: @Derek It was possible in any version of HTTP that supported cookies.

Comment: TCP sessions get distinguished at the kernel level.  That is, this problem of differentiating sessions is solved by your operating system.  The various apps that use the network (like your browser) just make system calls.  I believe all modern operating systems use Network Sockets.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model, though Wikipedia might be too dense to start out with.

Comment: What is interesting is that a TCP session can span multiple page-loads. I.E. I can login to a site, and pre-login and post-login use the same TCP session. If I was saving off TCP sessions to files, that contained HTTP transactions, do I have any way of going back retroactively and knowing which order the HTTP sessions came across the wire, or is that data lost without manually time-stamping them as they happen?

Comment: @Derek 'TCP session' and 'TCP connection' are identical, and they are usually just described as connections, not sessions. What you are talking about is (1) *HTTP* sessions and (2) HTTP persistent connections (which are also TCP connections). If you log TCP reads and writes, the *order in the log* is the order they occurred in, and the cookie in the HTTP headers indicates what HTTP session they belonged to.